# How to add image in a question in Google Form via GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm developing a Google Active Script to generate a Google Form based on an Excel file with Quizziz template format... Questions are correctly generated, but I don't know how to insert images in CheckboxItem or MultipleChoiceItem. Main function is shown below:

```
/* KahootArray2GoogleForm KahootArray2GoogleFormResult
pArrayKahoot = array Kahoot a partir del que generaremos el formulario Google
(array format: 0.Question, 1.Option 1, 2.Option 2, 3.Option 3, 4.Option 4, 5.Option 5, 6.Correct Answer, 7.Time, 8.Image Link)
Devuelve un array de dos elementos: id, error
donde 
id = id del Google Form resultante; eoc undefined
error = mensaje de error; eoc undefined
*/
function KahootArray2GoogleFormItem(pArrayKahootQuestion, pForm) {

  var lKahootArray2GoogleFormItemResult = [undefined, undefined];

  Logger.log(pArrayKahootQuestion[KahootQuestion.Question]);
  Logger.log(pArrayKahootQuestion[KahootQuestion.CorrectAnswer]);

  if (pArrayKahootQuestion[KahootQuestion.CorrectAnswer].indexOf(",") > -1) {
    // Multiple corrrect answers question -> check box options question
    var lQuestion = pForm.addCheckboxItem();
  }
  else {
    // Only one corrrect answer question -> radio button options question
    var lQuestion = pForm.addMultipleChoiceItem();
  }

  lQuestion.setTitle(pArrayKahootQuestion[KahootQuestion.Question]);

  **/* How to add image between question and choices? */**

  var lChoices = [];
  AddChoice(lQuestion, lChoices, pArrayKahootQuestion[KahootQuestion.Option1], (pArrayKahootQuestion[KahootQuestion.CorrectAnswer].indexOf(KahootQuestion.Option1) > -1))
  AddChoice(lQuestion, lChoices, pArrayKahootQuestion[KahootQuestion.Option2], (pArrayKahootQuestion[KahootQuestion.CorrectAnswer].indexOf(KahootQuestion.Option2) > -1))
  AddChoice(lQuestion, lChoices, pArrayKahootQuestion[KahootQuestion.Option3], (pArrayKahootQuestion[KahootQuestion.CorrectAnswer].indexOf(KahootQuestion.Option3) > -1))
  AddChoice(lQuestion, lChoices, pArrayKahootQuestion[KahootQuestion.Option4], (pArrayKahootQuestion[KahootQuestion.CorrectAnswer].indexOf(KahootQuestion.Option4) > -1))
  lQuestion.setChoices(lChoices);

  lQuestion.setPoints(1);

  return lKahootArray2GoogleFormItemResult;

}
```

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

### Unfortunately, so far this is only possible from the UI of the form creation, but not with Apps Script

There is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/36765518) that has already been filed on [Public Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker). I recommend you to give it a "star" to indicate Google the importance of the feature.

Comment: Thanks!!! Star given. Hoping Google solve this request as soon as possible.